# Are assignment operators "required" to return?

Tags: c++, standards

According to the C++ standard, can I be sure that assignment operators for built-in variables return (the original value)?

Or is this implementation dependent (yet simply have most popular compilers implemented this)?

Comment: They don't return the old or the new *value*. They return the *variable* being assigned to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed:

> **5.17 Assignment and compound assignment operators**
>
> The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators all group
> right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left operand
> and *return an lvalue referring to the left operand*.

This applies to built-in types. With user-defined types it can return anything.

Comment: to what types does this section refer? Surely, there are known exceptions (I wouldn't be surprised if they exist within the standard)

Comment: This just needs an extract of §13.6 (built-in operators) to be exact IMO: "The candidate operator functions that represent the built-in operators defined in Clause 5 are specified in
this subclause." The Note in that section clarifies that all constraints in section 5 apply to built-in operators.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you mean by "the original value".

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int i;
    std::cout << (i = 1.9) << "\n";
}
```

prints `1`.  The assignment expression yields the new value of the LHS (namely 1), not the "original value" of the RHS (1.9).

I'm not sure whether that's what you meant to ask about.

Answer (score 3):

> According to the C++ standard, can I be sure that assignment operators for build in variables return (the original value)?

**Edit** I get it now, I think. Yes: you can be sure that the built-in types return the original value *by reference* after `operator=, *=, /=, -=, +=, ^=, ~=, &= and |=`.

<strike>"For build in variables" is a bit cryptic to me. However,</strike>

```
X makeX()
{
    return X();
} // must have accessible copy constructor

// ...
X x;
x = makeX(); // ... _and_ assignment operator
```

> Or is this implementation dependent

It should **not** be (***edit** see standard reference by UncleBens*)

Comment: Your snippet does not use the assignment operator.

Comment: @UncleBens: ah, eternal mistake. Corrected the obsolete sample :) Thx

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is guaranteed that all assignments and augmented assignments on predefined types work that way.

Note however that user defined types assignments or augmented assignments can instead for example return `void`. This is not good practice and shouldn't be done (it raises the surprise effect on users - not a good thing), but it's technically possible so if you are writing for example a template library you should not make that assumption unless it's really important for you.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. Operator semantics will simply not work otherwise.

Comment: Could you please reference some paragraph in the Standard for that?

Comment: This completely ignores the possibility of a perfectly valid `T operator=(const T&) const { T other = /*blabla*/; return T; }` - this in fact happens a lot in expression template engines. Of course, 'value' types shouldn't surprise their users in this way,

Comment: The answer still doesn't make sense, without an example/explanation. In 99% of the cases, one doesn't use the return value. It not being there would really be a minor inconvenience.

Comment: @sehe returning a copy where a reference suffices is legal, but is going to be massive overhead.

Comment: @UncleBens, if you chain non-const operators, e.g. `T t1, t2, t3; T1 OP t2 OP t3;`, not having `OP` return a reference would prevent compilation.

Comment: @moshbear: again completely ignoring popular idioms where operators will return _other_ types that still allow operator chaining just fine: `AssignmentExpr Expression::operator+=(const Expression&) const` ? Also, the overhead will not be 'massive': it will just be the minimum required for the task. As you can see, there is more than just intrinsic types :) I don't always like overgeneralizing answers, but completely underestimating the problem domain is the other extreme.

Comment: @sehe: can you give examples of idioms utilizing return-by-value operators?

Comment: @sehe: as in the names of the idioms, not an example of their usages

Comment: @moshbear: can you give me the name of the idiom that returns the lvalue by reference? (Also, I'd think ['expression templates' qualifies as a pattern](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Expression-template), see my first comment)