# Easier way to make class to work with operators?

Tags: c++, class, operator-keyword

Here, I have a class called `Value` which simply can get and set `float`.

```
class Value
{
public:
    Value(float f)
    :f(f){};
    float get()
    {
        return f;
    }
    void set(float f)
    {
        this->f = f;
    }
private:
    float f;
};
```

And I want my class to be able to work like the following example.

```
Value value(3);
std::cout << value * 2 - 1 << std::endl; // -> 5
std::cout << value == 5 << std::endl; // -> true
value /= 2; 
std::cout << value << std::endl; // -> 2.5
```

Should I manually add all operator methods to my class?

Or would there be any easier solution to treat `Value` like `float`?

Comment: Do some research about *conversion operators*. And note that classes like that generally make the code harder to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that having both implicit conversions to and from `float` could lead to ambiguity in some cases.

Comment: As it stands, your `Value` class is just a *more annoying to use* `float`. I'm not sure you need it *at all*

Comment: Whatever you do, you have to bracket `value == 5` (i.e. `(value == 5)`)

Comment: @Caleth Maybe this is just by way of experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idiomatic implementation of the relevant arithmetic, equality and stream operators.

Notes in the comments inline.

See also the note about the consequences/benefits of allowing implicit conversion from float.

```
#include <iostream>

class Value
{
public:
    // Note - this constructor is not explicit.
    // This means that in an expression we regard a float and a Value on the
    // right hand side of the expression as equivalent in meaning.
    // Note A.
    //      =
    Value(float f)
    :f(f){};

    float get() const
    {
        return f;
    }

    void set(float f)
    {
        this->f = f;
    }

    // Idiom: unary operators defined as class members
    // 
    Value& operator *= (Value const& r)
    {
        f *= r.f;
        return *this;
    }

    Value& operator -= (Value const& r)
    {
        f -= r.f;
        return *this;
    }

    Value& operator /= (Value const& r)
    {
        f /= r.f;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    float f;
};

// Idiom: binary operators written as free functions in terms of unary operators

// remember Note A? A float will convert to a Value... Note B
//                                                          =
auto operator*(Value l, Value const& r) -> Value
{
    l *= r;
    return l;
}

auto operator-(Value l, Value const& r) -> Value
{
    l -= r;
    return l;
}

auto operator<<(std::ostream& l, Value const& r) -> std::ostream&
{
    return l << r.get();
}

// Idiom: binary operators implemented as free functions in terms of public interface
auto operator==(Value const& l, Value const& r) -> bool
{
    return l.get() == r.get();
}

int main()
{
    Value value(3);
    // expressions in output streams need to be parenthesised
    // because of operator precedence
    std::cout << (value * 2 - 1) << std::endl; // -> 5
    // ^^ remember note B? value * 2 will resolve to value * Value(2) because of
    // implicit conversion (Note A)
    std::cout << (value == 5) << std::endl; // -> true
    value /= 2; 
    std::cout << value << std::endl; // -> 2.5
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `get()`, you could have a [conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) to `float` type:

```
operator float() const { return f; }
```

If you also want to enable operations that change the value (such as `/=`), you can have similar non-const operator that returns a reference, or you can add those operators manually.

But if you want to have a class that behaves exactly like `float`, it might be better to use `float` instead of having the `Value` class at all.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented `/=` and `==` operators :

you can use of this page for learn more...
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm

```
class Value
{
public:
    Value(float f) : f(f) {};

    operator float() const
    {
        return f;
    }

    void set(float f)
    {
        this->f = f;
    }

    Value &operator /=(float num)           // e.g. value /= 2;
    {
        this->f = f / num;
    }

    bool operator==(const float& a) const    // e.g. std::cout << value == 5 << std::endl; // -> true
    {
        if(this->f == a) return true;
            return false;
    }

private:
    float f;
};
```

**main :**

```
int main()
{
   Value value(10);

    value /= 5;

    cout << value << endl;
    cout << (value == 5) << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `operator /=` should return `Value&`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118600/are-assignment-operators-required-to-return

Comment: @Ville-Valtteri yes, i improved it...  Thanks