# How to make the SWIG binded class to use operators in Lua?

Tags: c++, lua, swig, operator-keyword

Here, I have a class called `Value` which simply can get and set `float`.

```
class Value
{
public:
    Value(float f)
    :f(f){};
    float get()
    {
        return f;
    }
    void set(float f)
    {
        this->f = f;
    }
private:
    float f;
};
```

And I want my class to be able to work like the following example in Lua.

```
local value = my.Value(3);
value = value * 2 - 1
if (value == 5) then
    print("succeed");
else
    print("failed");
end
```

And it should output the following result.

```
succeed
```

How should I correct my class so I can use operators with it?

Comment: I'd consider taking a look at Sol. Exposing raw C++ classes is never going to work entirely painlessly.

Comment: Asking again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239390/easier-way-to-make-class-to-work-with-operators

Comment: @StoryTeller this one is a different question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to overload every operator you want to use, i.e. `operator*`, `operator+`, and `operator==`.   Unfortunately, the comparison operator does not work because Lua only considers the `__eq` metamethod if both operands in the comparison have the same metatable.  From the [Lua users wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MetatableEvents):

> **__eq** - Check for equality. This method is invoked when "myTable1 == myTable2" is evaluated, but only if both tables have the exact same metamethod for __eq.

You can work around that by wrapping the other operand in the comparison into the `Value` constructor.

```
%module my
%{
class Value
{
public:
    Value(float f) :f(f) {};
    Value operator*(float f) const {
        return this->f * f;
    }
    Value operator-(float f) const {
        return this->f - f;
    }
    bool operator==(Value const &rhs) const {
        return this->f == rhs.f;
    }
private:
    float f;
};
%}

class Value {
public:
    Value(float f);
    Value operator*(float f) const;
    Value operator-(float f) const;
    bool operator==(Value const &rhs) const;
};
```

```lua
local my = require("my")

local value = my.Value(3);
value = value * 2 - 1

if (value == my.Value(5)) then
    print("succeed");
else
    print("failed");
end
```

Comment: Thank you and congrats for gaining 5,000 reputation! I'm glad I just made you so ;)

Comment: @ZackLee I had a better idea than calling the metamethod.  Just wrap `5` into the constructor for `Value`.  See the updated answer.